# openWithCompletionHandler is not returning on my devices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, icloud, uidocument

I am struggling with odd behavior I encounter when I'm trying to open a UIDocument from iCloud that has been created using another device. When I call ***openWithCompletionHandler*** it never completes.

Here's how I reproduce the behavior:

1. I created a new UIDocument on my iPad and stored it in iCloud
2. Then I removed the same app, but from iPhone
3. I run the app from XCode on my iPhone
4. So far the iPhone is clean because the app was removed
5. When the app runs on iPhone for the first time, it calls ***openWithCompletionHandler*** method which hangs and nothing is happened. It doesn't reach a block with code to execute after the ***openWithCompletionHandler*** operation concludes.

It works only when I create a new UIDocument and store it in iCloud from iPhone. Then if I do the same steps (1-5) but on iPad I encounter a similar behavior.

Here is the source code that I have:

```
if ([query resultCount] == 1)
{
    NSMetadataItem *item = [query resultAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *url = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];

    _progressDoc = [[ProgressDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

    [_progressDoc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success)
        {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
             addObserver:self 
             selector:@selector(progressDocumentHasChanged:) 
             name:UIDocumentStateChangedNotification 
             object:nil];

            NSLog(@"Progress Document opened from iCloud");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"failed to open Progress Document from iCloud");
        }
    }];
}
```

Has anybody encountered a similar issue?

I also tried to download the file manually using the method below, but still same behavior...

```
- (BOOL)downloadFileIfNotAvailable:(NSURL*)file {
    NSNumber*  isIniCloud = nil;

    if ([file getResourceValue:&isIniCloud forKey:NSURLIsUbiquitousItemKey error:nil]) {
        // If the item is in iCloud, see if it is downloaded.
        if ([isIniCloud boolValue]) {
            NSNumber*  isDownloaded = nil;
            if ([file getResourceValue:&isDownloaded forKey:NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey error:nil]) {
                if ([isDownloaded boolValue])
                    return YES;

                // Download the file.
                NSError *error;
                NSFileManager*  fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                BOOL success = [fm startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:file error:&error];
                if (success) {
                    NSLog(@"Started download at URL: %@", file);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Failed to start download at URL: %@: %@", file, error.localizedDescription); 
                }                 
                return NO;
            }
        }
    }

    // Return YES as long as an explicit download was not started.
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this as I am coming across the same issue

Comment: Nope. It doesn't happen for me in iOS 6.0